# Uncheck Radio buttons with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, material-ui

I wish to be able to uncheck radio buttons, Idea is like this: if I click on some radio button, it is going to be checked, if I click on another field, this another field is going to be checked instead BUT if I click on field which is already checked, I wish to uncheck it so all fields are empty. I tried to catch the moment of being checked or unchecked but seems like opposite to checkboxes, Radio buttons don't have this field. does anyone has idea how to achieve that?

```
setTests = (key, e) => {
    console.log(e.checked)
    if (e.checked) {
      // this.setState({[key]: null})
      console.log('works')
    }
  }
RadioGroup
            value={this.state.test_mode}
            style={{ display: "block" }}
            onChange={e => this.setTests({ "test_mode", e.target })}
          >
            <FormControlLabel value="before" control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="before tests" />
            <FormControlLabel value="progressing" control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="progressing" />
            <FormControlLabel value="done" control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="done" />

          </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Yah, with radio buttons, you can't uncheck a radio button by clicking on it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Below is an example of how to do this. Instead of using the `onChange` of the `RadioGroup`, you use the `onClick` event of the `Radio`. If the new value matches the current value in state, then set the value to empty string.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Radio from "@material-ui/core/Radio";
import RadioGroup from "@material-ui/core/RadioGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex"
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3)
  },
  group: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1, 0)
  }
}));

export default function RadioButtonsGroup() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("female");

  function handleClick(event) {
    if (event.target.value === value) {
      setValue("");
    } else {
      setValue(event.target.value);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.formControl}>
        <FormLabel component="legend">Gender</FormLabel>
        <RadioGroup
          aria-label="gender"
          name="gender1"
          className={classes.group}
          value={value}
        >
          <FormControlLabel
            value="female"
            control={<Radio onClick={handleClick} />}
            label="Female"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            value="male"
            control={<Radio onClick={handleClick} />}
            label="Male"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            value="other"
            control={<Radio onClick={handleClick} />}
            label="Other"
          />
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Uncheck Radio]

Comment: well this only works if there is a default value set on the state.